# Async csv.writer from database

Tags: python, database, asynchronous, pyodbc

I've got a Python script that extracts data from a DB into a CSV file. I'm using [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) to access the DB and execute the queries. I'm also using csv.writer to output the query into a file:

```
with open(source_filename, 'w', newline='') as source_file:
    csv.writer(source_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC).writerows(db_cursor)
```

Because the script outputs all tables in a database I'd want to speed up the extraction by using background processing instead of one after the other. Is there a way to do this in Python?

I tried using Multiprocessing but couldn't get past some pickling errors.

Thanks

Comment: you need to be very careful with threading shared resources...

Answer (score 1):

[Multithreading](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/stdlib2.html#multi-threading) is a lighter weight way to achieve parallelism, but as the documentation says, *"Threading is a technique for decoupling tasks which are not sequentially dependent."* You'll need to know where your dependencies are in order to decide what to do in parallel.  It's not obvious that submitting multiple queries in parallel to a database backed by a single disk store will return results any faster than submitting them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create multithread processes; the original process starts a new thread, which does the db access and file write, while the original process continues with its business. 
       Also, rather than creating multiple processes accessing the database to retrieve the same data, use a single background process for that. It'll be safer, faster, and easier to debug.